# Laptop Malfunctions After UPS Failure? I Have Got What I Deserved

Tags: boot, troubleshooting, bios, ups, hp-pavilion

My UPS failed today and laptop ceased working. UPS failed me before 1 time and it was when laptop was on standby but nothing happened to the laptop however. Also there were times when laptop was working and UPS failed as well but laptop did not malfunction. This time i have got what i deserved. I should have been seriously suspicious when UPS failed me 1st time but i did not take it seriously.

When i turn on laptop, power button light and power led are blinking, i hear laptop working and DVD drive also is activated as usual but screen does not show anything.

**I have filmed it and here is the video:**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2MPiVShoik

Mouse, USB Hub, power supply and LAN cable were connected to laptop at the time of failure. Do you think it was power breakout that went through power cable or LAN cable? I did not smell smoke or anything.

What can be the problem? I already paid $150 to replace cooler i spoiled. I also paid $50 for 2GB of RAM and this laptop means more to me than any other. I could send it to HP lab, but labor and parts will cost a lot.

Don't know what to do, continue with this laptop which i bought in 2006 or buy new HP laptop which is a lot stronger and costs twice as much to labor and part replacement.

**UPDATE!** I have solved the problem by reinserting RTC battery. In the process i have got the following screen:

[image]

What means **"System CMOS Checksum Bad"**? I have saved changes and laptop is in working condition, that is hardware speaking.

Comment: Please post your specific brand and model of Notebook. Sometimes there are model specific solutions

Comment: HP Pavilion 5282ea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried booting with the battery removed.  I have seen this on a Dell with a bad batttery.

Many UPS systems will not pass power when there is a failure so it may be something else.

As to repair or repalce... It is usually very expensive to repair a laptop, especially a mainboard.  If a power surge was the issue, fixing one piece amy only get you working til the next component fails

Comment: It was not power surge since power came back after ~30 minutes. Well mainboard costs $290 to replace... New stronger laptop with 3 years of warranty costs $982. You can see it here: http://i55.tinypic.com/2956b5w.png

Comment: So it will not start with battery out?  Can you test the AC adapter with a volt meter and see if it is giving correct power.  As to shopping for new, that is really outside the scope of this forum.  Having said that, three year factory backed warranties are good.  All perils if you can afford it.

Comment: Tested with AC adapter and battery - nothing. Sent for repair for a price quote.

Answer (score 4):

You may have fried the mainboard in which case it will be worth scrapping it and starting fresh.

Just out of curiosity - why do you have a UPS for your laptop, surely if the power goes you have a laptop battery to kick in?

Comment: Unfortunately it was too late. How would i know there is a power outage coming? It failed on the first outage.

Answer (score 1):

Well, chances are that it is fried, and you are right, a UPS helps to protect your computer, but only for the connections routed through it, so if your LAN cable does not go through it, it could send a board-killing power spike right to your electronics. I have seen a lightening strike kill every computer in a building through the network cabling.

I live in an area with quite a few electrical storms in the summer, and I always unplug any non-essential network cables when a storm is coming, and I even unplug things like my printers totally.

So as to the question of whether to fix or start new: There is no question, that I would buy a new computer. The amount you save is more than offset by the faster computer, which you will like and appreciate, but also by the fact that you will be covered by a new warranty for at least a year usually.

Comment: The wasn't any storm or lightning. There was not power surge since half an hour passed until power was back. That laptop that i thought to buy has 3 years of warranty.

Comment: @Boris_yo I did not mean that to imply that it could only happen by lightening, but let's face it, that is a pretty good way, which demonstrates the point I was trying to make. You are right that it can happen any number of ways, especially if you live in a region with a shaky power grid. I actually agree with buying a laptop with a long warranty. I always buy a very high-end laptop, and a 4-5 year warranty, if it is offered. I am not a warranty freak either, and I don't buy extended warranties for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect AC power, remove the battery, hold the power button down for 30 seconds, connect AC Only, see if it will boot or show a POST screen.

If no joy, disconnect AC, insert battery and try.

Post your specific product number for more specific answers or solutions for your HP

## 2

[image]