# Administrator account is corrupted?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, administrator, user-profiles

After successfully solving **[my previous problem](https://superuser.com/questions/310113/laptop-malfunctions-after-ups-failure-i-have-got-what-i-deserved)** i stumbled upon another shortly after. Once i logged into my administrator account i have noticed the following missing:

1. Quick launch which also cannot be enabled
2. Shortcuts in right slidable panel on desktop
3. Access to many folders is denied
4. Nothing in **Start > Programs**

Additionally Atomic Alarm crashed every time i logged into Windows as well as Adobe Shockwave installation which usually appeared.

After logging off and on again, i have got this message:

> Windows cannot load user's profile but has logged you on with the default profile for the system.
>   DETAIL: Incorrect function

Should i remove and recreate same admin profile? I have tried changing rights which did not help. Question is, programs that worked with original administrator profile will work with same but new account?

My computer's specifications:

- Windows XP SP3 32-bit Home Edition
- HP Pavilion 5282ea
- 2.5GB of RAM

Answer (score 0):

The 'old' profile still exists, it's just gained some 'inconsistency' that means XP refuses to use it (this can happens when the computer gets stuck in 'Saving your settings' at power-down and you get so fed up waiting that you pull the power plug)

This is a 'common' problem and (I seem to recall) involves creating a new Administrator account and 'copy' the 'old' profile to the new account using MS Profile Edit tool (which 'fixes' whatever the problem is whilst changing all the SID's and Registry references) ...

See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysdm_userprofile_copy.mspx