# Why am I unable to connect to the home hotspot?

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, connection, wireless-router

I use WPA-PSK with password and my router and having trouble connecting to it with **[my laptop I fixed yesterday](https://superuser.com/questions/310113/laptop-malfunctions-after-ups-failure-i-have-got-what-i-deserved)** by resetting RTC (CMOS?) battery. Although my laptop additionally has **[errors with my administrator account](https://superuser.com/questions/387083/administrator-account-is-corrupted)**, I still think it has nothing to do with current problem because I tried connecting from the guest account and additional administrator account I have created.

Here are the settings of router:

[image]

I do not remember the error message exactly, but it said something about checking range to hotspot and area of networking... All other laptops connect without problems.

Comment: What are the DHCP and WLAN setting of that laptop? Maybe something else is set with windows firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my wireless NIC cannot support **WPA2 with AES** because when i changed this setting to **WPA with TKIP** i have successfully connected. Initially there were thoughts about old service pack, however this appeared to be not the case since i have latest Windows XP service pack.

The wireless NIC is **Intel Pro Wireless 3945BG** and laptop was bought in 2006.

Problem solved! Thanks to everyone.